# Issue in integrating php-redisearch with laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, redisearch

I have installed the plugin MacFJA/php-redisearch using the following command

`composer require macfja/redisearch`

Issue:

[image]

Complete code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
use DateTime;
use FKRediSearch\RediSearch\Setup;
use MacFJA\RediSearch\Redis\Client\ClientFacade;

class CommandName extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'command:commandName';
    protected $description = 'Command description';
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function handle()
    {
        $clientFacade = new ClientFacade();
    }
}
```

Can someone share why the issue is thrown?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. The current snippet does not include the autoloader

Comment: updated full code, please check @NicoHaase

Comment: Which version of that package did you install? `MacFJA\RediSearch\Redis\Client\ClientFacade` is not part of the latest stable release yet

Comment: I have installed version "1.4"

Comment: @NicoHaase Can you please share any other suitable package?

Comment: Suitable for what? Why not simply wait for a stable release of that package?

Comment: @NicoHaase I  need php redisearch plugin for laravel 8

Comment: So, how could I help you with that? Why not ask the maintainers of that project to release a proper version? In the meantime, why not use the code as it is currently published?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @NicoHaase said (and [here also](https://github.com/MacFJA/php-redisearch/issues/18)), `MacFJA\RediSearch\Redis\Client\ClientFacade` is not available in versions 1.x, and as for now, the version installed by Composer is the version `1.4.0`.

The next version (that will be `2.0.0`) is not ready yet, but is not far away. It's this version that have the class `MacFJA\RediSearch\Redis\Client\ClientFacade`.

---

But the version `1.4.0` can be used in Laravel as well.

The documentation is here: https://github.com/MacFJA/php-redisearch/tree/1.4.0#readme

But to summarize it should be something like:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
use DateTime;
use Predis\Client;
use MacFJA\RediSearch\Search;

class CommandName extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'command:commandName';
    protected $description = 'Command description';
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function handle()
    {
        $client = new Client(['scheme' => 'tcp', 'host' => 'localhost', 'port' => '6379', 'db' => 0]);
        $search = new Search($client);

        $results = $search
            ->withIndex('person')
            ->withQuery('Doe')
            ->withHighlight(['lastname'])
            ->withScores()
            ->search();
        // Do something with $result
    }
}
```

---

You can also look at this lib: [macfja/redisearch-integration](https://packagist.org/packages/macfja/redisearch-integration).
Its goal is to reduce a part of the boilerplate and add PHP object mapping (like Doctrine ORM)